# Formulating a hierarchical Bayesian model for gambling (Pymc3)

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I am quite new to Bayesian modeling and trying to wrap my head around how to choose hyperpriors and formulate the model. I am using Pymc3

My example data is gambling related. People play a 'balloon' task, where they roll a fair 6-sided die and earn points until they bank the money keep rolling until they hit a 1 and lose the amount they accumulated this round. I have $i...N$ subjects that play $T_i$ trials resulting in an unbalanced dataset ~17000 obs. (not all people play the same amount of trials).

I want to model the probability of the players banking their earnings $P(stop)$. I have 3 variables that I am trying to explain the data with:

- $points$ - accumulated points for each trial, for each subject. This is a discrete variable that takes values from 0 to ~ 500, e.g. [20,40,100,120...].
- $steak_{high}$ - a counter that accumulates when the die rolls 5 or 6.
- $steak_{low}$ - a counter that accumulates when the die rolls 2 or 3.
- $stop$ - a dummy that indicates if the subject stopped at trial $i$.

I can easily pool all subjects together and estimate a logistic linear model using

```
pm.glm.GLM.from_formula('stop ~ seqearn + high_count + low_count', data, family = pm.glm.families.Binomial())
```

which gives meaningful results, such as people increasing their probability to stop, as points increase.

However, I would like to model a simple hierarchical model that allows *each* subject to express variability, and at the same time, use their underlying similarity (they all want to maximise end number of points) alá [this blog post](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2014/03/17/bayesian-glms-3/).

Here is the 'adapted' code:

```
def run_HM():

points = data.points.astype(theano.config.floatX)

with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model:

    mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_alpha', mu=0., sd=100**2)
    sigma_a = pm.Uniform('sigma_alpha', lower=0, upper=100)
    mu_b = pm.Normal('mu_beta', mu=0., sd=100**2)
    sigma_b = pm.Uniform('sigma_beta', lower=0, upper=100)

    # Intercepts

    a = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=mu_a, sd=sigma_a, shape=len(data.subject.unique()))
    b = pm.Normal('beta', mu=mu_b, sd=sigma_b, shape=len(data.subject.unique()))

    # Error
    eps = pm.Uniform('eps', lower=0, upper=100)

    # Expected value
    stop_est = a[data.subject.values] + b[data.subject.values] * data.points.values

    # Likelihood
    y_like = pm.Normal('y_like', mu=stop_est, sd=eps, observed=data.stop)

with hierarchical_model:
    # Use ADVI for initialization
    mu, sds, elbo = pm.variational.advi(n=100000)
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=hierarchical_model.dict_to_array(sds)**2, 
                   is_cov=True)

    hierarchical_trace = pm.sample(5000, step, start=mu)
```

However, the results are not very good. Several distributions does not converge and some of them look multimodal.

1. **What would be useful hyperpriors for $points$ and $steak_{high/low}$? Obviously, the normal distribution is a poor choice**
2. **How do I specify dependence on several variables?** In the blog post, floor level is the only variable that goes into the model.

Thanks!